# NodeJS sqlite3 SELECT query cached

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'm creating a discord bot (DiscordJS) using NodeJS and using sqlite3 to store 2 sets of data.

I open the DB with:

```
 let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/games.db', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        ...
}
```

Later on, I store a certain message in a table called promotedGames (id INCREMENTAL, server INT, channel INT, messageID INT)

And when I query the db with

```
db.all(`SELECT * FROM promotedGames WHERE gameID = ${row.id}`, (err, promotedGamesResults) => {
...
```

It always returns the first ever game stored, I've no idea why this could be happening at all.

Steps taken so far:
- Restarted the Node App
- Deleted the sqlite3 database and redone it
- Deleted the node_modules folder and reinstalled all the packages

Any hints of what could be that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show complete code for `db.all(`SELECT * FROM promotedGames WHERE gameID = ${row.id}`, (err, promotedGamesResults) => {
...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You try to search your gameID with row.Id , row id in sqlite is a built-in counter for the rows you have insert in a table  IT IS NOT the column gameID .

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to return the records matching the `${row.id}`
It runs the query passed as an argument and for each result from the database, it will run the callback.
Therefore is better to use db.each() when you intend to retrieve some items from the database.

```
db.each(`SELECT * FROM promotedGames WHERE gameID = ${row.id}`, (err, promotedGamesResults) => {
```

...

PS: `db.each` is used when you need to return all the rows and work on the selected returned data set.